# Apache + Php-FPM + APC : mode_deflate not compressing HTML output

Tags: apache-2.2, php-fpm, alternative-php-cache, mod-deflate

I have prepared a server to run a Magento instance with: Apache + Php-FPM + APC

The problem I have is that Apache is not compressing the HTML output from the Magento PHP scripts.

In my .htaccess I have:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
```

I also tried compressing all with:

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
```

But I had no luck.

Zlib compression is disabled:

```
php_flag zlib.output_compression on
```

My guess is that this have something to do with Php-FPM or APC, but I'm not sure about what the problem is.

The mime-type returned for the uncompressed pages is:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** The problems seems to be with anything that is processed by PHP, if I copy the html output to a .html file and then fetch it, it will be compressed, if I rename the same file to .php and fetch it the output won't be compressed. Here are the headers:

**[[RESPONSE HEADER HTML FILE]]**

```
Date Fri, 29 Aug 2014 20:03:13 GMT
Content-Encoding gzip
Last-Modified Fri, 29 Aug 2014 19:53:19 GMT
Server Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
ETag "24002f-34e71-501ca0144a75d"
Vary Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Type text/html
Cache-Control max-age=10800
Connection Keep-Alive
Accept-Ranges bytes
Keep-Alive timeout=5, max=100
Content-Length 20884
Expires Fri, 29 Aug 2014 23:03:13 GMT
```

**[[RESPONSE HEADER PHP FILE]]**

```
Date Fri, 29 Aug 2014 20:05:19 GMT
Server Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Connection Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive timeout=5, max=100
Transfer-Encoding chunked
Content-Type text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

And the request headers:

**[[REQUEST HEADER HTML FILE]]**

```
Pragma no-cache
Accept-Charset ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate,sdch
Host dev.go-parts.com
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.8
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.63 Safari/537.31
Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Cache-Control no-cache
Connection keep-alive
```

**[[REQUEST HEADER PHP FILE]]**

```
Pragma no-cache
Accept-Charset ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate,sdch
Host dev.go-parts.com
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.8
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.63 Safari/537.31
Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Cache-Control no-cache
Connection keep-alive
```

Comment: What were the full request / response headers when you tested if compression works?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I have added the response headers for 2 pages with the same content one with HTML and the other with PHP extension, the first on is compressed and the other one no. Any idea what I can do? =(

Comment: What are the request headers for these requests?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I added the request headers too.

Comment: The apache repsonse headers seem to indicate you are not using mod_php, but could be restricted by configuration. Can you confirm how you are executing your PHP? (mod_php, as a CGI, fastcgi, fcgid or proxying to FPM) If you are proxying to a fastCGI server or to an FPM pool then apache itself is not mapping the request to the file system and so your htaccess file would not be read.